# sql calculate percentage repartition

Tags: sql

I want to calculate the percentage for the following table:

```
type , quantitie

A    ,  25
B    ,  5
C    ,  20
D    ,  10
E    ,  15
```

the expected result would be

```
type , percentage

A    ,  33,3
B    ,  6,66
C    ,  26,66
D    ,  13,33
E    ,  20
```

Answer (score 0):

You would normally use window functions for this.  I prefer a ratio:

```
select type, quantitie * 1.0 / sum(quantitie) over ()
from t;
```

The `* 1.0` is because some databases do integer division.  If you want a value between 0 and 100, use `* 100.0`.